# Is unit ball in $L_2(0,1)$ closed in $L_1(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request

More exactly, let $L_1(0,1)$ be the space of integrable functions $f :  (0,1)->R \to \mathbb{R}$ with norm $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx|dx$. Let B be subset of $L_1(0,1)$ such that $f \in B$ if and only if $\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx <= 1 \leq 1$. Is B a closed set in $L_1(0,1)$?

In other words, if $f_n$ converges to f in $L_1(0,1)$ and $\int |f_n(x)|^2 dx <= 1 \leq 1$ for all n, does it imply that $\int |f(x)|^2 dx <= 1 \leq 1$? (Note that convegrence in $L_1(0,1)$ does not imply convegrence in $L_2(0,1)$).

Comment: Yes. Find a subsequence that converges a.e., and use Fatou's Lemma.

Answer (score 2):

Lets show that for every converges sequence $\{f_n(x) \} \in L_2(0,1)$ in $L_2(0,1)\subset L_1(0,1)$ the limit $f(x) \in L_2(0,1). $

So we know that $ \lim_{n->\infty} \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|dx = f(x)$.

Acording to  [Fatou's Lemma.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma)

$$ \int_0^1 |f(x)|dx \le \lim_{n->\infty} \inf \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|dx$$

so 
$$ \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 \le \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2 \le 1 $$ . $$=> f(x) \in L_2(0,1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^1$ there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges almost everywhere to $f$ (this is part of the usual proof of the completeness of $L^p$). Then $|f_{n_k}|^2$ converges almost everywhere to $|f|^2$. By Fatou's lemma
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}
\int_0^1|f(x)|^2\,dx=\int_0^1\liminf_{n\to\infty}|f_{n_k}(x)|^2\le\int_0^1|f_{n_k}(x)|^2\le1.
$$